# HTML-based Clipboard Data Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clipboard

I'm often copy-pasting from html-based sources to other html input fields. Sometimes it seems the source or destination tries to preserve html formatting/layout but generally I want this stripped.

Google Sheets and Co are particularly guilty of this; if I copy from an html source, Google will try to preserve formatting on paste, and white-space is usually messed up.

Is there anything I could do via CSS, HTML attributes, or JS that will prevent html meta-data from being included when copying from HTML sources?

Comment: You want to do this to your own page or you trying to make this on any page?

Comment: Look for a "paste special" operation in the destination software.

Comment: from my own page, if possible.